# Ionic 3 splashscreen bottom gap on Iphone X and load twice

Tags: ionic3, xcode9

I am update my xcode to 9 and build the app, discover that the splashscreen will display twice and the iphone X will have the bottom gap in the first displayed splashscreen, below is the image:
[image]

And then will load the splashscreen secondly with no bottom gap:
[image]

My info is :

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.15.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.15.2
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
System:
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
Node       : v7.10.0
npm        : 5.5.1 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004 
nvironment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : not set
Misc:

backend : legacy
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: couple questions.  Did you go through the [migration guide](http://blog.ionic.io/ios-11-checklist/) so that you use the new web view and change the html meta tag?  Did you perform `ionic resources` after migrating?  I had a similar issue which was solved by using WKWebView.

Comment: Thanks, I am using WKWebView for this project at the beginning, so i guess no migration needed.

Comment: Do you have `viewport-fit=cover` in your index.html?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine, just the splashscreen will display twice and first load have a bottom gap.

Comment: I can confirm that this is an issue. I'm experiencing the same with my app.

Comment: @tmuecksch do you have any solution?

Comment: @tmuecksch I am already using storyboard not the lagacy, but the 2732x2732 px screen is not idea because of not perfect fit with the screen in all different size iphone.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I just tried - it doesn't fix the problem... I'm still investigating...

Comment: @Nulra Have you tried this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-splashscreen-bottom-gap-on-iphone-x-and-load-twice/111254/8 ?

Comment: @tmuecksch Yes, tried and solved the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
There is now a stable version available.
In 4.5.4 the issue has been fixed.

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add ios@4.5.4
```

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

Wait for the next version of cordova-ios. It will be fixed then.
Until then try the following workaround:

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add ios@nightly
```

Source: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-splashscreen-bottom-gap-on-iphone-x-and-load-twice/111254/8

Comment: I m still having the issue in ios@4.5.5